# PySpark Dataframe column with json row type in python

Tags: python, json, pyspark

In a pysparkdataframe (= df) , I have a column 'json' with JSON entries. I want to have all the "RemainingTimes" values and convert in to a Pandas Dataframe. I solved this with a For_loop, but it runs very slowly.

Can anyone help me ?

A single cell looks like this:

```
{ "RXBatteryCharge": null, "RXBatteryLoad": null, "RXBatteryTime": null, "RemainingTime": [0, 47], "RemoteEnable": [15, 0, 0], "SelectedMap": null, "SignalDoor": false, "SignalFailure": false, "SignalInfo": false, "SpinningSpeed": null, "StandbyState": null, "StartTime": [0, 0], "Status": 5, "TargetTemperature": [-32768, -32768, -32768]}
```

And this is my Solution:

```
l1 = []

for i in range(df.count()):
  l = [df.select('json').collect()[i][0]['RemainingTime']]
  l1 = l1.append(l)


df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
```

Comment: df.select('json.RemainingTime').toPandas()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [from_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python//reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) to parse a column with a json string into a struct. Then you can select the element of the struct you are interessted in.

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

schema = "RXBatteryCharge string, RXBatteryLoad string, RXBatteryTime timestamp, RemainingTime array<int>, RemoteEnable array<int>, SelectedMap string, SignalDoor boolean, SignalFailure boolean, SignalInfo boolean, SpinningSpeed double, StandbyState string, StartTime array<int>, Status int, TargetTemperature array<int>"

df.withColumn("parsed_json", F.from_json("json", schema)).select("parsed_json.RemainingTime").show()

#+-------------+
#|RemainingTime|
#+-------------+
#|      [0, 47]|
#+-------------+
```

When using `from_json` a schema string must supplied that matches the element of the json string.